# Android incoming call interception , call forwarding

Tags: android, android-ndk

I would like to know how to intercept incoming calls and also how to forward them. I know there are several questions regarding this topic here and elsewhere on the net, but all the answers use the android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE action which is broadcast always after the phone begins to ring and the call screen is shown.
That's why I'm looking for a solution where i could intercept the call in an early stage before any notification (ringing etc..) has been done. I would like to know if maybe this is possible on a platform level in native code and if yes how ? Or perhaps with some kind of trick with the SDK ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you can't do it in Java, you can't do it in the NDK. Most of the time the opposite is true: You can't do MOST things on Android in the NDK.

I don't know of a way to do that, and frankly doubt it exists: It would be a huge security hole if you could download an application that would forward calls to another number.

Comment: There are several apps in the market that forward calls: http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/search?st=call+forwarding

Comment: OK, though my primary answer still stands: He was asking if there was a way to do it in the NDK, and if there's no way to do it in Java then there's no way to do it in the NDK.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this source code, it may help you : http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing apps in Android can forward a call based on a given number. All they can do is forward all or nothing. There's one app in particular ([cBlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cloud4apps.cBlocker)) that can forward calls on schedule besides blocking incoming and outgoing calls and SMS based on rules.